# Should interrupts be disabled while communicating with external SPI flash?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, embedded-resource

I am using an external SPI flash with my STM32 MCU.

I am wondering Can the following scenario lead to data corruption in flash or in the read buffer?

If an ISR triggers at the same time, while the communication (Read/Write/Erase) with flash is ongoing from the main process, and the ISR takes up some clock cycles, then return back to the communication. Can it cause any such issue? How may I go on to investigate it?

Note: ISR doesn't access the SPI bus.

Comment: You'd probably need to look at the specs for the flash chip and see if it has any timing requirements for communication. But you could also probably mitigate any issue by using DMA for your flash communication, which would continue to run no matter what the CPU was doing.

Comment: IIRC, the Read/Write/Erase, are more _minimum_ time, but review the specs as suggested above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you'll be fine.  As the master device on the SPI bus, your STM32 generates the clock signal which determines the rate of communication.  If something happens to slow down your CPU the only thing you might notice is that there is a longer-than-necessary delay between some transitions on the clock line, but that will not cause any issues with the SPI devices you are communicating with.

If you're not sure about this, try putting delays of 100 microsecond in lots of different places in your code and see if the SPI communication gets messed up.

Answer (score 2):

No, You should be OK. Why? Because the only danger is receive register overwrite

SPI master can only receive data when transmitting, then you cant send another portion of data in the poling mode to the SPI is you are in the ISR. In DMA mode it is even more less probable.